# Python distutils.core.run_setup fails when running from within script?

Tags: python, installation, subprocess, distutils

I'm trying to run a Python setup script from within a python script. That is, instead of:

```
python path_to/setup.py build --build-base="build_dir" install --prefix="install_dir"
```

which works fine. I want to be able to call

```
from distutils.core import run_setup
args = ['build', '--build-base="build_dir"', 'install', '--prefix="install_dir"']
run_setup("path_to/setup.py", script_args=args, stop_after='run')
```

from within another Python script (as automated/on the fly installation). This does not seem to work at the moment as the call returns the error

```
RuntimeError: 'distutils.core.setup()' was never called
 -- perhaps 'setup.py' is not a Distutils setup script?
```

which is strange since calling it from outside the script works. Is there something wrong with this approach? The setup.py script looks normal:

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.command.build_py import build_py
# ...
if __name__ == '__main__':
    setup( ... )
```

Alternatively, I'm thinking about just calling "subprocess" from the script, but then want to ensure I'm using the same Python instance/runtime as the running Python instance (in case many python versions are installed). How could I do this, ensure to call the top command from a subprocess with the same python?

Comment: have you tried executing it as a cmd?

Comment: Yes, as mentioned it works as normal without calling distutils from within a script.

Comment: well i mean you can execute cmd instructions from within python, have you tried that?

Comment: Yes that is the subprocess approach, but then I need to somehow ensure that the same python runtime/interpreter is used.

Comment: try this then, I think you have to escape the inner quotes, not sure:

osCmd = "python path_to/setup.py build --build-base=\"build_dir\" install --prefix=\"install_dir\""

os.system(osCmd)

Comment: Yes, I know I can do that, but how do I ensure that the python called is the same as the one used by the cmd call? In case "cmd python" does not point to the same installation/interpreter.

Comment: "*ensure I'm using the same Python instance/runtime as the running Python instance*" Use [`sys.executable`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html#sys.executable)